# 'function' undefined only in Edge and Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, sharepoint

I'm developing a we page in SharePoint but only in Internet Explorer 11 and Microsoft Edge the onclick referenced function throws an error. In Chrome, Firefox, Opera it's ok.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function BuildCategory( element )
{
    for( let button of pathButtons )
    {
        button.style.borderBottom = "1px solid #999999";
        button.style.boxShadow = "0.5px 1.5px 0.5px #AFAFAF";
        button.style.color = "#888888";
        button.style.backgroundColor = "transparent";
    }
    element.style.backgroundColor = "#FEFEFE";
    element.style.color = "#111111";
    element.style.borderBottom = "1px solid #709BE5";
    element.style.boxShadow = "0.5px 1.5px 0.5px #709BE5";

    careerArea = element.innerHTML;
    BuildPath( careerPath, careerArea, careerRole );
}

function BuildRole( element )
{
    for( let button of roleButtons )
    {
        button.style.color = "#888888";
        button.style.borderBottomColor = "#000000";
    }
    element.style.color = "#111111";
    element.style.borderBottomColor = "#709BE5";

    careerRole = element.innerHTML;
    careerRole = careerRole == 'Trainee' ? Trainee : careerRole == 'Proficient' ? Proficient : careerRole == 'Senior' ? Senior : careerRole;
    BuildPath( careerPath, careerArea, careerRole );
}
</script>
<span class="PathTitle">
    BlackBox Career Path
</span>
<div class="PathSelector">
    <span class="PathButton Sixth" onclick="BuildCategory( this )">Testing Process</span>
    <span class="PathButton Sixth" onclick="BuildCategory( this )">Tools</span>
    <span class="PathButton Sixth" onclick="BuildCategory( this )">Certification</span>
    <span class="PathButton Sixth" onclick="BuildCategory( this )">Consulting</span>
    <span class="PathButton Sixth" onclick="BuildCategory( this )">QA/PI</span>
    <span class="PathButton Sixth" onclick="BuildCategory( this )">PM</span>
    <span class="PathButton Sixth" onclick="BuildCategory( this )">All Categories</span>
</div>
<div class="RoleSelector">
    <span class="RoleButton Octet" onclick="BuildRole( this )">Trainee</span>
    <span class="RoleButton Octet" onclick="BuildRole( this )">Junior</span>
    <span class="RoleButton Octet" onclick="BuildRole( this )">Proficient</span>
    <span class="RoleButton Octet" onclick="BuildRole( this )">Senior</span>
    <span class="RoleButton Octet" onclick="BuildRole( this )">QA Lead</span>
    <span class="RoleButton Octet" onclick="BuildRole( this )">Expert</span>
    <span class="RoleButton Octet" onclick="BuildRole( this )">QA Manager</span>
    <span class="RoleButton Octet" onclick="BuildRole( this )">QA Consultant</span>
    <span class="RoleButton Octet" onclick="BuildRole( this )">All Roles</span>
</div>
<div class="CourseSelector" id="courseSelector">
</div>
```

In non Microsoft browsers the function works and throws no error.

I get 'BuildCategory' is undefined when I click a 'PathButton' or 'BuildRole' is undefined when clicking a 'RoleButton'.

Comment: Use the F12 dev tools to examine the console output.  Maybe there's a Content Security Policy (CSP) in place that's blocking the inline script.  See the [MSDN Dev Guide](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/dev-guide/security/content-security-policy#inline-script-and-onclick-handlers).

Comment: Just solved, issue was that I'm using for..of/in statement, which isn't compatible with IE and some versions of Edge X_X. I had a long time viewing why the console said that a ';' was missing in ´<span class="PathButton Sixth" onclick="BuildCategory( this )">Testing Process</span>´. I decided to put alerts in the function and I noticed that the alert inside the for was not executing. I used the classic for(var ...) and everything is ok

Answer (score 1):

Just solved, issue was that I'm using `for..of/in` statement, which isn't compatible with IE and some versions of Edge. I had a long time viewing why the console said that a ';' was missing in `<span class="PathButton Sixth" onclick="BuildCategory( this )">Testing Process</span>`. I decided to put alerts in the function and I noticed that the alert inside the for was not executing. I used the classic `for(var ...)` and everything is ok